# Why do these classes only compile when in the same file?

Tags: java, classpath, javac

I have this directory `c:\abcd` it has no files in it, but has a subdirectory efgh.

```
C:\abcd>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is B411-D580

 Directory of C:\abcd

02/08/2014  06:57 PM    <DIR>          .
02/08/2014  06:57 PM    <DIR>          ..
02/08/2014  07:01 PM    <DIR>          efgh
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               3 Dir(s)   1,990,201,344 bytes free
```

The efgh subdirectory, as you can see, has 3 files. `Blah.java`, `Greeter.java` and `comb.java`

`Blah.java` has a class, `Greeter.java` has a class.

`comb.java` happens to contain the code of `Blah.java` and `Greeter.java`, so it has two classes. It's superfluous but it's to demonstrate something. Which is a case of comb compiling while one of the individual files (`Blah.java`) does not.

```
C:\abcd>cd efgh

C:\abcd\efgh>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is B411-D580

 Directory of C:\abcd\efgh

02/08/2014  07:01 PM    <DIR>          .
02/08/2014  07:01 PM    <DIR>          ..
02/08/2014  07:00 PM               130 Blah.java
02/08/2014  07:00 PM               216 comb.java
02/08/2014  07:00 PM                99 Greeter.java
               3 File(s)            445 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   1,990,201,344 bytes free
```

These are the contents of the three files

**`C:\abcd\efgh>type Blah.java`**

```
package efgh;

class Blah {

    Greeter greeter = new Greeter();

    public static void main(String[] args) {}

}
```

**`C:\abcd\efgh>type Greeter.java`**

```
package efgh;

class Greeter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {}

}
```

**`C:\abcd\efgh>type comb.java`**

```
package efgh;

class Blah {

    Greeter greeter = new Greeter();

    public static void main(String[] args) {}

}

class Greeter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {}

}
```

**`C:\abcd\efgh>javac comb.java`**

So, comb.java compiles.

I see it produced `Blah.class` and `Greeter.class` which is further proof that it compiled, but I'll now delete those `.class` files. As that makes my point, that `javac comb.java` works.

```
C:\abcd\efgh>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is B411-D580

 Directory of C:\abcd\efgh

02/08/2014  07:02 PM    <DIR>          .
02/08/2014  07:02 PM    <DIR>          ..
02/08/2014  07:02 PM               341 Blah.class
02/08/2014  07:00 PM               130 Blah.java
02/08/2014  07:00 PM               216 comb.java
02/08/2014  07:02 PM               261 Greeter.class
02/08/2014  07:00 PM                99 Greeter.java
               5 File(s)          1,047 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   1,990,201,344 bytes free

C:\abcd\efgh>del *.class
```

Now I'll compile them individually. And it doesn't work so well.. compiling `Blah.java` gives an error.

```
C:\abcd\efgh>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is B411-D580

 Directory of C:\abcd\efgh

02/08/2014  07:03 PM    <DIR>          .
02/08/2014  07:03 PM    <DIR>          ..
02/08/2014  07:00 PM               130 Blah.java
02/08/2014  07:00 PM               216 comb.java
02/08/2014  07:00 PM                99 Greeter.java
               3 File(s)            445 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   1,990,201,344 bytes free

C:\abcd\efgh>javac Greeter.java

C:\abcd\efgh>javac Blah.java
Blah.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
   Greeter greeter = new Greeter();
   ^
  symbol:   class Greeter
  location: class Blah
Blah.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
   Greeter greeter = new Greeter();
                         ^
  symbol:   class Greeter
  location: class Blah
2 errors
```

I know that technically, my classpath isn't set right. Because, given that I have no classpath variable set, it is defaulting to a classpath of current directory. And given the package names, the classpath should be `c:\abcd`. And if I set it to that then it compiles `blah.java` individually.

```
C:\abcd\efgh>javac -cp c:\abcd Blah.java
```

But that still doesn't explain why comb.java compiles fine with no switches:

```
C:\abcd\efgh>javac comb.java

C:\abcd\efgh>
```

I understand the package statement in `comb.java` applies to the `Blah` class and the `Greeter` class. I don't see why when compiling `comb.java` I don't need to set the classpath specially, whereas I do when compiling `javac Blah.java`.

Comment: add import statements

Comment: @M.Sharma They are all in the same package.

Comment: please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475491/javac-compiling-a-java-file-which-uses-other-classes-in-it

Comment: not an answer, but on a tangent, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470109/difference-between-classpath-and-sourcepath  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441760/differences-between-classpath-and-sourcepath-options-of-javac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already made all the analysis, and the final point is quite simple: `comb.java` doesn't *need* any classpath because it is fully self-contained: `Greeter` referenced from `Blah` is there in the same file.

Generally, `javac` needs to consult the classpath while compiling a class A, which references a class B, which is *not* on the list of files passed to it.

For example, try `javac Blah.java Greeter.java` and it should work as well.

Answer (score 2):

You're compiling without specifying a output "root" for the compiler to build up a package hierarchy from - so it just puts the class files in the same directory as the source files. Then it tries to find the classes later on, but it can't find classes in the `efgh` package, because you're already in the `efgh` directory and you haven't set your classpath correctly.

Options:

- Compile from the source root:

  ```
  c:\abcd> javac efgh\Greeter.java
  c:\abcd> javac efgh\Blah.java
  ```
- Compile specifying an output root, and putting that on the classpath the second time:

  ```
  c:\abcd> javac -d ..\bin Greeter.java
  c:\abcd> javac -d ..\bin -cp ..\bin Blah.java
  ```
- Both!

  ```
  c:\abcd> javac -d bin efhj\Greeter.java
  c:\abcd> javac -d bin -cp bin efgh\Blah.java
  ```

As for which `comb.java` compiles - it doesn't have any dependencies on other classes, so the compiler doesn't need to try to find `efgh.Greeter` or `efgh.Blah`. It's only failing for `Blah` because it's failing to find `efgh.Greeter`.